# Использование WebGL на Java

Tags: gwt, webgl, java, opengl

Есть ли Java-обертка для WebGL, например, в составе GWT?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[GwtGL](http://code.google.com/p/gwtgl/)

Используйте гугл, эту информацию я нашел в 1 запрос - первый результат

Comment: А он просто обертка (как JOGL, например) или навороченная библиотека?

Comment: Не имею ни малейшего понятия и считаю использование оберток подобного рода абсолютным безумием и бредом, всего-лишь погуглил за вас.

В доках копайтесь сами, или вы хотите чтобы это я тоже за вас делал?

Comment: У меня всё приложение на Java + GWT. Думал, что кто-то поделится своим опытом. На форуме ни одной темы с обсуждением WebGL, а тем более из Java :(

Comment: А что вы хотели?

Если вы хотите стать одним из первых разработчиков использовавших новую технологию - вам всему прийдется учится самому и наступать на "невидимые грабли".

Ну и потом делится своим опытом на форумах.

Если же вы не можете разобраться с базовым инструментом сам - не используйте новых технологий и выбросьте эту идею из головы. Лишь зря потратите время, я вас уверяю

На самом деле действительно хорошей информации по webGL довольном мало и ее будущее туманно ( thank you Bill )

Если технология приживется - тогда и будут вам ресурсы, инструменты и сообщества.